# Hibernate Java - Unexpected AST Node

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a Spring Boot application using Hibernate 5. I having a custom `@Query` for the repository.

```
public interface TeamResourceRepository extends CrudRepository<ResourceItem, Integer> {

    @Query("Select i from ResourceItem as i JOIN i.resourceCategories as c WHERE c.ID = ?1")
    List<ResourceItem> findByCategory(int id);

    @Query("Select i from ResourceItem as i JOIN i.tags as t WHERE (t.description = ?1 "
            + " OR i.name LIKE  ?1%) AND i.isActive ORDER BY i.name")
    List<ResourceItem> findByTag(String search);
}
```

However, I am receiving the following error `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: . near line 1, column 138 [Select i from com.midamcorp.resource_server.model.ResourceItem as i JOIN i.tags as t WHERE (t.description = ?1  OR i.name LIKE  ?1) AND i.isActive ORDER BY i.name]`

I have looked at some other questions on the topic, but none seemed to mirror my issue. All appears to be pretty standard SQL (JOIN, OR, LIKE, etc), so I am not sure where the issue is.

I have using MS SQL Server as my backend; any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT

Code for ResourceItem

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "Midamcorp", name = "ResourceItem")
public class ResourceItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "resources")
    private List<ResourceCategory> resourceCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "TagsResources", schema = "Midamcorp",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ResourceID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TagID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FileID")
    private FileResource file;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "IsActive")
    private boolean isActive;

    public ResourceItem() {

    }

    public ResourceItem(int iD, List<Tag> tags, FileResource file, String name) {
        ID = iD;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.file = file;
        this.name = name;
    }

// getters and setters here }
```

Comment: How your class `ResourceItem` Looks like? Please add the code

Comment: @Jens, it has been added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the whole query as in the exception:

```
Select i from com.midamcorp.resource_server.model.ResourceItem as i JOIN i.tags as t WHERE (t.description = ?1  OR i.name LIKE  ?1) AND i.isActive ORDER BY i.name
```

and looking at the error that column 138 is problematic, than you should look at `i.isActive`. I guess `i.isActive = true` will fix it.

Comment: That was indeed correct. For my case, it was i.isActive = 1. I appreciate the help, it seemed like a rather odd error for the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be in the LIKE with a param clause.
Try to concatenate the param with the wildcard:

```
OR i.name LIKE  CONCAT(?1,'%')
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it still gives the same error.